# plot a column chart with two y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Aim: simultaneously display columns and points of two different datasets, both taken from the same sites (x-axis).

I am able to plot a column chart of discrete site names (x) and continuous weight data (y). I have also been able to add an appropriately scaled second y axis, to plot points at each site, representing other continuous weight data of a much smaller scale than on the primary y axis.

However, the points seem to be using the primary y axis scale as coordinates and not the new secondary y axis, as intended. How do I ensure the new points are plotted against the new y-axis scale, while maintaining the primary column plot as it is?

Thanks

data:

```
Site_No (x) = 1:10
Total_Solids (y) = 30, 35, 32, 50, 55, 57, 45, 49, 55, 46
TOC (y2) = 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.45, 1.03, 2.4, 1.9, 1.8, 1.1, 1.6
```

Code:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Site_No, y = Total_Solids)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Site_No, y = TOC)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Total Solids (g)",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./20, name = "Total Organic Carbon (g)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient to "rescale the scale". You also have to rescale the data to be plotted on the secondary axis using the inverse of the rescaling factor applied to the scale:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Site_No = c(1:10),
  Total_Solids = c(30, 35, 32, 50, 55, 57, 45, 49, 55, 46),
  TOC = c(1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.45, 1.03, 2.4, 1.9, 1.8, 1.1, 1.6)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Site_No, y = Total_Solids)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Site_No, y = TOC * 20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Total Solids (g)",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./20, name = "Total Organic Carbon (g)"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that was super easy LOL. Additionally, how can I remove point atom site 10 but leave the column?

Comment: Quick and easy option: Set the value to NA, i.e. do e.g. `df$TOC[df$Site_No %in% c(10)] <- NA`

Comment: is it possible to change the points into horizontal lines? My first thought was to plot the point data as `geom_col` again, but only display the top of the column (not the sides), then adjust the width slightly narrower than the primary columns. I can't see anything about this in `colour` notes though..

Comment: Sure. Replace the geom_point by `geom_segment(aes(x = Site_No - .45, xend = Site_No + .45, y = TOC * 20, , yend = TOC * 20))`. The .45. is half of the default width (= .9) of the bars.

Comment: Thanks @stefan.

On a similar plot, I'd also like to add error bars, which I can do with `geom_errorbar`, but is it possible to get rid of the `ymin` for any columns where the SD is high and exceeds the x-axis? I can remove the lower bar for ALL only, using `ymin = Total_Solids`